# The function called from Context wouldn't work (React)

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am using Context to call the helloWorld function in my React app. It works in onClick, but for some reason it doesn't work when I define it in a function.

```
export const TestProvider = () => {
  const helloWorld = () => console.log('hello world');

  return (
    <TestContext.Provider value={{
      helloWorld
    }}>
  )}

export const useTestContext = () => {
  const context = useContext(TestContext)
  return context
}
```

- It works

```
const { helloWorld } = useTestContext()

return (
  <button onClick={helloWorld} />
)
```

- It wouldn't work

```
const { helloWorld } = useTestContext()

  const handleHelloWorld = async () => {
    await helloWorld
  }
```

How can I fix to work `handleHelloWorld` here?

Comment: If you add perentesis to `helloWorld` it doesn't work? I mean `await helloWorld()`.

Comment: A callback is supposed to be called by somebody else. In the last snippet handleHelloWorld is a callback, and helloWorld is not, it's your responsibility to call it.